# Finite State Machine with Guards in PHP?

Tags: php, state-machine

Does anybody know a `finite state machine` that has **guard** feature in **PHP** ?

Comment: The FSM Package in Pear doesn't have guard.I used to work with tungsten-FSM in java.

Comment: what is guard feature?

Comment: @hakre when a state is going to transit some conditions are going to be checked and the result should be true. these conditions are called `guard`

Answer (score 5):

Using [PEAR's FSM](http://pear.php.net/package/FSM) ([usage example](http://www.indelible.org/php/FSM/guide.html#building-a-finite-state-machine)), you can use the action callback to return the next state if the guard fails, like so:

```
$payload = '';
$fsm = new FSM('STATE1', $payload);
function guard1($symbol, $payload) {
    if ($payload == 'something') {
        // Guard success, allow transition
        return;
    }
    else {
        // Guard fail, return to previous state
        return 'STATE1';
    }
}
$fsm->addTransition('SYMBOL1', 'STATE1', 'STATE2', 'guard1');

$fsm->process('SYMBOL1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at ezComponents Workflow. Allows you to design workflows with many objects and add in conditionals and states.

Answer (score 1):

check out:
https://github.com/chriswoodford/techne/tree/v0.2

I think it has the functionality that you're looking for. You define a transition and then can associate a closure that gets called before the transition is processed. here's a simple example:

#### Define your FSM

```
  $machine = new StateMachine\FiniteStateMachine();
  $machine->setInitialState('off');
```

#### Define the transitions

```
    $turnOff = new StateMachine\Transition('on', 'off');
    $turnOn = new StateMachine\Transition('off', 'on');
```

#### Add a guard to the turnOn transition

```
    // flipping the switch on requires electricity
    $hasElectricity = true;
    $turnOn->before(function() use ($hasElectricity) {
        return $hasElectricity ? true : false;
    });
```

#### Transition from off to on

```
  $machine->flip();  
  echo $machine->getCurrentState();
  // prints 'on'
```

#### Transition back to off

```
  $machine->flip();  
  echo $machine->getCurrentState();
  // prints 'off'
```

#### if the $hasElectricity variable had been set to false, the outcome would look like this:

```
  // oops, forgot to pay that electricity bill
  $hasElectricity = false;

  $turnOn->before(function() use ($hasElectricity) {
      return $hasElectricity ? true : false;
  });
```

#### Then, if you try to transition from Off -> On

```
  $machine->flip();  
  echo $machine->getCurrentState();
  // prints 'off'
```

In order to determine where a transition was completed, you'd just have to compare the previous state to the current state.

Answer (score 0):

The Conditions in the Metabor Statemachine
https://github.com/Metabor/Statemachine
can be used as Guards (3rd parameter in Transition constructor).
See Example:
https://github.com/Metabor/Statemachine-Example/blob/master/Example/Order/Process/Prepayment.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, consider to avoid external links since they can broken over time, instead include some relevant code with explaination in your answer

Comment: I have given myself an opportunity to implement some state machine with Metabor. The only problem is that without a step by step explanation it is totally difficult to follow what is going on there. Is there any tutorial available out there that I can read?

Comment: The example isn't very clear. The conditions must implement a ConditionInterface which isn't in the same project. However the object requiring the ConditionInterface requires a context variable. https://github.com/Metabor/Statemachine-Example/blob/master/Example/Order/Condition/AuthorizedSuccessful.php Where is this context variable acquired from? How do you set it up for the state machine?